# Error when outputting xml with php

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

I'm trying to implement Google maps on my site. I'm following the tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=sv

However, I can't output xml properly when looping through the database. In the tutorial there are three examples on how to output xml. I get "error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document" both when using example two and three.

Som what's up with this, why am I getting this error message. Since the code is from Google I assume it's correct, so my best guess is that I have som kind of hidden sign in my file.

Any help much apprecieated!

```
<?php  

 require("dbinfo.php"); 

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password); 
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
$newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
$newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);  
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
$newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
} 
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

**Edit:**

```
Here's an example of my output which might give some more insights on what's going on:

<marker name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940"      
lng="-122.340141" type="restaurant">
<marker name="Buddha Thai &amp; Bar" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA"    
lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391" type="bar">
<marker name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561"    
lng="-122.356445" type="restaurant">
</marker>
</marker>
</marker>
</marker>
```

So the problem seemts to be that the marker node doesn't close for each loop. Instead the closing  nodes are just added at the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875870/xml-extra-content-at-the-end-of-the-document

Comment: Thank's for your reply. I saw this question but it doesn't really explain waht is wrong, it just says use someting else (htmlentities). I wan't to know why this piece of code doesn't work. It seems strange that google would put bad code in a tutorial for one of there most used products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already assigned `$node` to the **markers** node at the top and you are overwriting it in the while loop...that's why it's messing up after the first iteration. Replace your `while` loop with this:

```
<?php
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
    $marker = $dom->createElement("marker");  
    $node->appendChild($marker);   
    $marker->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
    $marker->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);  
    $marker->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
    $marker->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
    $marker->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, I gave i at a go, bur the problems remains with all the closing <marker> nodes att the end. Have you tried this code?

Comment: How strange, could you post the full code? Maybe I have some invisible charachters in my code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T5eYB6Ud. I have removed the Db connection code and put it with dummy data.

Comment: Yes, I tried your code and it really works. But when I try it with my db connection and the while loop (instead of your foreach) I still get the same error. Maybe the problem is with the while loop?

Comment: Maybe...in your original code, can you change `while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){` to `while ( ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))!==false){` and try again?

Comment: Nope, no luck! Can yoy try it with the db? Here's an sql document that you can import that builds the db right away: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=sv

Comment: Here is the link with my db trial, it works perfectly fine. http://pastebin.com/XuS8qe3m. Here is the result - http://pastebin.com/nkfwitbV. **Btw, it's your original code i'm using, just put the localhost in quotes**

Comment: Great, I can't believe I missed this. Thank's a lot for helping so much!